# How would one access the events data from a web calendar for use in displaying in a mobile app?

Tags: swift, database, server, calendar, icalendar

I've got a calendar that has iCalendar standard integration, but I'm not sure how to really get the data from the iCal link and bring it over to the iOS app I'm developing. I'm using JTAppleCalendar, and I've watched his video on how to stream data from a server, but I'm still not quite sure how to get the iCal event data into a form/place that is able to be utilized by the app.

I've already searched around and watched videos but I was unable to find an answer. I've also tried importing the calendar to google calendar for use through that API, but I'm unable to get that working either.

I want to be able to have the calendar remain public and for the user to be able to see the events without having to sign in to anything (like google for example) or have to add the iCal on their own for it to work.

This may be a simple question, but I'm still in the very early stages of learning iOS dev, so sorry about that.

Comment: In what form do you get the data?

Comment: I just have access to the iCal subscription link. I need some way to get that to usable data.

Comment: Therefoer, this doesnt seem to be a question about the library specifically. It seems to be a question of **how does one get data from iCal**

Comment: This is correct. I thought that I made that clear in the question, I just mentioned JTAppleCalendar for context. I apologize if I was unclear.

Comment: No youre good. I got confused when i saw the calendar in the topic. cheers 